# jQuery different presentation same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX call in jQuery (see blow) which works very well. It creates a new table on success with all my data in. However, I now want to use the **same script** for a completely different page and present the data in a different way. What would you recommended? How can I remove the presentation logic and call a different presentation while using the same ajax function etc:

```
    success: function (data) {
        // Check if we had any campaigns returned.
        if (data.objects.length == 0) {
            // Message to show if user has not created any Campaigns yet.
            bootbox.alert("You don’t have any Campaigns yet.");
        } else {
            // Loop each campaign object and add to the table.
            $.each(data.objects, function () {
                $('#campaign_table').append("<tr><td>" +
                    "<a class='editable editable-click username2' data-title='Enter username' data-placement='right' data-type='text' href='#' data-original-title='' title=''>" +
                    this.name +
                    "</a>" + "</td></tr>");
                console.debug(this.name)
                // this = object in array
                // access attributes: this.Id, this.Name, etc
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: Assigning body of each page a class and checking if body has class A do this else do this

Comment: I would recommend using a MV* framework ([backbone JS](http://backbonejs.org/) f.ex). If this is too much, you could look into [underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Comment: I'd recommend creating an object whose properties are the things that change - alert, id, classes etc..  Then have an execute method (or similar) that does the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that exposes the result of the response:

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

---

```
getData().done(function (data) {
    //display the data however you want
});
```